# how can I concatenate these mixtures

Tags: matrix, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I have a matrix. for each row of this matrix I made a Gaussian mixture, how can I concatenate these mixtures.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question. Are you asking that how you can write down the likelihood of the bigger matrix when each of its rows is characterized by a separate Gaussian mixture model?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: are the rows independent from each other?

Comment: they are independent but the same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

under independence assumption, the total likelihood of a matrix $\mathbf{M}$ given that each of its rows defined by a Gaussian mixture model $f_i(X|\vec{\theta_i})$ is equal to:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{M}) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} f_i(X_i|\vec{\theta_i})
\end{equation}

where $N$ is the number of rows in matrix $\mathbf{M}$, and $X_i$ denotes the i-th row in $\mathbf{M}$. The parameter vector $\vec{\theta_i}$ are supposed to be the mixture ratio parameters, mean and variance of the Gaussian distributions in the i-th distribution.